# How can i change the json formate after request in c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am sending the Json format like this in PostMan

```
    {
  "number": 2106887,
  "date": "09/10/2018",
  "degree":"BE"
  "Students": [
    {
      "Branch": "ABK015",
      "Doc": "NCE",
      "Description": "Testing",
      "dni": "1016035232",
      "Name": "ABCE",
      "Gender": "M",
      "Title": "Univercity",
      "email": "abc@in.com",
    },
    {
      "Branch": "ABK016",
      "Doc": "NCE",
      "Description": "Testing1",
      "dni": "1016035233",
      "Name": "ABCE",
      "Gender": "M",
      "Title": "Univercity",
      "email": "abcd@in.com",
    }
  ]
}
```

In controller level i am doing the validation of all fields.
After validation how can i convert the above json string to below format

```
{

  "Students": [
    {
      "number": 2106887,
      "date": "09/10/2018",
      "degree":"BE"
      "Branch": "ABK015",
      "Doc": "NCE",
      "Description": "Testing",
      "dni": "1016035232",
      "Name": "ABCE",
      "Gender": "M",
      "Title": "Univercity",
      "email": "abc@in.com",
    },
    {
      "number": 2106887,
      "date": "09/10/2018",
      "degree":"BE"
      "Branch": "ABK016",
      "Doc": "NCE",
      "Description": "Testing1",
      "dni": "1016035233",
      "Name": "ABCE",
      "Gender": "M",
      "Title": "Univercity",
      "email": "abcd@in.com",
    }
  ]
}
```

And aftre converting, i want to insert to database.
How to convert in c#?  Please help me.

And the below code is the class for students:

```
public class Students
{
    [Required]
    public string Branch{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Doc{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string dni{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Gender{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string email{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string degree{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string date{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string number{ get; set; }
}
```

And i am deserializing here

```
var requestBody = requestContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JObject jxxx = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(requestBody);
```

Please refer the updated code

Comment: By creating that structure and serializing.

Comment: Please show us some code, including your relevant models and controller methods.

Comment: @Amy `var requestBody = requestContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                JObject jxxx = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(requestBody);`
here the requestContent is json format

Comment: The json you return will result from the model youre returning if you're following normal conventions. As @Amy said, we need to see your models and controller action

Comment: @GregH i have created the class for Students with all fields

Comment: Your json is not in correct format. Copy your json and go to c# any class. Click on edit > Paste Special > Paste Json As Classes. If that will generate the class then it is in correct format. Your json has "{ }" braces on start and end. So thats why it is not converting your json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DeserializeAnonymousType` method. First create a `template` object

```
var template = new {number = "", date = "", degree = "", Students = new Students[0]};
```

now deserialize to temporary json object:

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(input, template);
```

After this you can copy info from json header to `Students` with linq:

```
var students = jsonObject.Students.Select(s =>
{
    s.number = jsonObject.number;
    s.date = jsonObject.date;
    s.degree = jsonObject.degree;
    return s;
}).ToArray();
```

Also note, that your input JSON is not valid: it missing comma afetr `degree` value.

Demo is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Z7oB8)

Comment: Hi, here how can i add the Student list?

Comment: @Chandu replacre `ToArray` with `ToList` and then you can call `students.Add(...`

Comment: @Alexs, i have one more doubt.  How to convert all the tagnames(keys) to lowercase? like `Branch to branch, Doc to doc, Description to description`

Comment: @Chandu you can use JsonProprrty https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
"Students": [
    {
      "number": 2106887,
      "date": "09/10/2018",
      "degree":"BE"
      "Branch": "ABK015",
      "Doc": "NCE",
      "Description": "Testing",
      "dni": "1016035232",
      "Name": "ABCE",
      "Gender": "M",
      "Title": "Univercity",
      "email": "abc@in.com",
    },
    {
      "number": 2106887,
      "date": "09/10/2018",
      "degree":"BE"
      "Branch": "ABK016",
      "Doc": "NCE",
      "Description": "Testing1",
      "dni": "1016035233",
      "Name": "ABCE",
      "Gender": "M",
      "Title": "Univercity",
      "email": "abcd@in.com",
    }
  ]
```

And then try this

```
var students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Students[]>(requestBody);
```